# How to resize web content based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a web page. It has two regions left and right content. Till now i am testing it on a particular window size where it is lying in center and size is exact fit. But as soon as i minimise it or open it on monitor of different size it is not getting resized based on it. How can i do it. here is the web link i am working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/efyJF/.

If you see, right now the content in side is fixed size. So, i need to scroll all the way to the right to see the end of right content border.

I feel like this is not the way the normal web pages work. How can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Dont use `px`, either use percents or `em`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you are looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aXsZK/)

The container has a property of `margin: 0 auto;` which puts it in the centre, and then the children divs take up a percentage of that parent div. The parent (#container) can be resized and the children will fill it up appropriately.

The mistake you made was using absolute positioning, this will perfectly align it for your screen, but other screens won't look the same.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my mistake. Now it looks way better. My only concern is can i make the height of container to adjust to window size reather than 500 px.  Why i need this is because my right content has overflow: auto. so it will have a scroll and window will have a scroll. it will be difficult to opereate two scroll bars. if i can limit my container to window size i dont have to think about scroll bar on window. Does it make sense?

Comment: I sort of understand you, just set height to 100% if thats what you need, or height:auto will let the browser decide how high it should be

Answer (score 2):

You can define your css value using percentage like `width: 20%` instead using fixed value. Or try to use css framework like [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) or [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/).